# Spring integration DSL creating JMS MessageDriver Channel Adapter in java 1.7

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to create a integration flow for JMS MessageDriverChannelAdapter through which I need to send message to the Kafka server. But I really 
stuck when I am trying to convert the the xml tag to dsl specific code, not able to convert the xml to required DSL. Can any one please provide
any pointer to it as I am not able to proceed over here.

I have created a MessageListenerContainer like this........

```
String brokerUrl = "tcp://101.11.102.125:31316";
String topic = "sometpoic"; 
String kafkaBrokerUrl = "101.11.102.125:1012";
String kafkaTopic = "kafka_Topic";

@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory conFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    ActiveMQTopic mqTopic = new ActiveMQTopic(topic);           
    conFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
    container.setConnectionFactory(conFactory);
    container.setDestination(mqTopic);
    container.setSessionTransacted(true);
    return container;
}
```

These are my input and output channels........

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel jmsInChannel() {
     return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel jmsOutChannel() {
     return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
}

And this is my JMS adapter flow............

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(listenerContainer())                      
                   .autoStartup(true))                     
                   .channel(jmsInChannel())                                              
                   .get();
}
```

Now I need to create a header-enricher like this but not able to covert this into DSL.

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="jmsInChannel" output-channel="jmsOutChannel">
<int:header name="kafkaBrokerUrl" value="${kafka.url}"></int:header>
<int:header name="kafkaTopic" value="${kafka.topic}"></int:header>
```

and I need to create a service-activator and call a kafka producer method form a different class like this in xml....

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="jmsOutChannel" ref="KafkaProducer" method="produceToJmsKafka"/>
<bean id="KafkaProducer" class="com.david.jms.JmsKafkaProducer"/>
```

So how to convert these above xml code to similar DSL specific code.

```
  After getting the compilation error I have tried like this...
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(listenerContainer())                      
                   .autoStartup(true))                     
                   .channel(jmsInChannel())
                   .enrichHeaders(new MapBuilder()
                                .put("brokerid", brokerid)
                                .put("topic", topic)
                                .put("source", source)
                                .put("fileType", fileType))
                   .handle("KafkaProducer", "produceToJmsKafka")
                   .get();
}

@Bean
public JmsProducer KafkaProducer() {
    return new JmsProducer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That may be like this:

```
@Value("${kafka.url}")
private String kafkaBrokerUrl;

@Value("${kafka.topic}")
private String kafkaTopic;

....
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(listenerContainer())                      
                   .autoStartup(true))                     
                   .channel(jmsInChannel()) 
                   .enrichHeaders(new StringStringMapBuilder()
                                            .put("kafkaBrokerUrl", kafkaBrokerUrl)
                                            .put("kafkaTopic", kafkaTopic))
                   .handle("KafkaProducer", "produceToJmsKafka")
                   .get();
}
```

From here I don't see reason to have those `MessageChannel` beans, especially like `publishSubscribe()`.

From other side since [DSL 1.1](https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/15/spring-integration-java-dsl-1-1-m1-is-available) we provide the implementation for Spring Integration Kafka Adapters.

Comment: Hi Artem, Thanks a lot for this answer, spring DSL is awesome. But I have some doubt on this. 
When implementing the JMS integration flow  enrichHeaders() facing a compilation error saying that 'The method enrichHeaders(MapBuilder<?,String,Object>) 
in the type IntegrationFlowDefinition<IntegrationFlowBuilder> is not applicable for the arguments 
(StringStringMapBuilder)'. When I cast to Map<String, Object>), then error came on run time.
Also in the JMS integration flow jmsOutChannel() is really not required, not sure about this. 
So could please provide some more pointer on this.

Comment: Hi Artem,   
After getting the compilation error I have tried like this. Edited the code in my original post. Not sure about the integration flow.
So can I do like this. Could you please provide any pointer on this.

Comment: I'd say that everything looks good to me. There is no reason in the `.autoStartup(true)`, of course, and I'm not sure that you need `.channel(jmsInChannel())` in between `.from()` and `.enrichHeaders()`, but I'm sure that this code should work.

Comment: HI Artem, My question is that, can I use MapBuilder() instead of StringStringMapBuilder(), because StringStringMapBuilder() is getting compilation error in my end.